# How can I change window managers in 13.04?

Tags: window-manager, 13.04

There used to be an option in the login area (lightdm) that allowed you to choose window managers, but that option seems to have disappeared in 13.04. I installed Awesome WM, but Ubuntu is not giving me the option of switching to it.